# How to Rename preciseDiff Key in moment-timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, countdown

How to Rename key of `preciseDiff` Function in `moment-timezone`?

**code:**

```
var duration = momentz.preciseDiff(0, 1528791845);
```

**output:**

```
1 year 8 hours 17 minutes 6 seconds
```

I will want to translate year, month and ... to another language.

```
year       año  
month      mes  
day        día  
hour       hora  
minute     minuto  
second     segundo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine you would have to replace it manually. Maybe another function?

```js
const es = {
    year: 'año',
    years: 'años',
    month: 'mes',  
    day: 'día',
    hour: 'hora',
    hours: 'horas',
    minute: 'minuto',
    minutes: 'minutos',
    second: 'segundo',
    seconds: 'segundos'
};
const translateWords = (dictionary, string) => string
    .split(' ')
    .map(word=>dictionary[word]||word)
    .join(' ');
const esString = translateWords(es, "1 year 8 hours 17 minutes 6 seconds");
console.log(esString); // 1 año 8 horas 17 minutos 6 segundos
```

Comment: my Output is dynamic, I mean may I have just minutes and seconds, or y m m s, or all of year month day hours and ..., Can You Update with my code please?

Comment: Give me an example of what the translations would be.

Comment: I updated my Question, The Problem is, my output Created automatically,it depent on `1528791845` value

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei I updated my answer. I guessed at some of the plural translations. Hopefully you get the idea.